# I can't create an onCheckedChanged listener for my RadioGroup

Tags: java, android, eclipse, radio-group

I'm trying to create an onCheckedChanged Listener for my RadioGroup, but eclipse is throwing erros at me. this is the code

```java
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

        if (checkedId == R.id.switchToFriends) {
            // some code
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.switchToUsers) {
            // some code
        }
    }
});
```

And from eclipse I get an error on `setOnCheckedChangeListener` suggesting to change it to setOnClickListener/setOnDragListener, and others.
On `new OnCheckedChangeListener()` it tells me to add unimplemented methods, and when I select that option it adds this :

```java
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

So I end up with this:

```java
rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        Log.d("chk", "id" + checkedId);

        if (checkedId == R.id.switchToFriends) {
            // some code
        } else if (checkedId == R.id.switchToUsers) {
            // some code
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

And it tells me to remove the `@Override` annotation from the method that I wrote.
Anyone knows why it won't let me override the method that way? I've checked the [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener.html) and the method it shows there uses the format that I try to override

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you imported the correct package `import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;` then the `@Override` will be correct

Comment: thank you, I didn't know there were different imports. I just copied the code from some posts I found.

Comment: I've also had that error. So It's important to make sure you got the right imports. Check on the android API as well

Answer (score 4):

You can directly add the listener with the ClassName

```
 radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

If, for example, you already are using a CompoundButton and associated OnCheckedChangeListener, you will not be able to import the RadioGroup class, but will still be able to access it directly using this solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have imported the wrong package.

You should import 
`android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener`

instead of 
`android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`